# Encode Decode of strings python

Tags: python, character-encoding, decode, encode

I have a list of html pages which may contain certain encoded characters. Some examples are as below -

```
<a href="mailto:lad%20at%20maestro%20dot%20com">
<em>ada&#x40;graphics.maestro.com</em>
<em>mel&#x40;graphics.maestro.com</em>
```

I would like to decode (escape, I'm unsure of the current terminology) these strings to -

```
 <a href="mailto:lad at maestro dot com">
<em>ada@graphics.maestro.com</em>
<em>mel@graphics.maestro.com</em>
```

Note, the HTML pages are in a string format. Also, I DO NOT want to use any external library like a BeautifulSoup or lxml, only native python libraries are ok.

**Edit** -

The below solution isn't perfect. HTML Parser unescaping with urllib2 throws a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

error in some cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unescape HTML entities, and URL-unquote.
The standard library has [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html?highlight=htmlparser#HTMLParser) and [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2) to help with those tasks.

```
import HTMLParser, urllib2

markup = '''<a href="mailto:lad%20at%20maestro%20dot%20com">
<em>ada&#x40;graphics.maestro.com</em>
<em>mel&#x40;graphics.maestro.com</em>'''

result = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(urllib2.unquote(markup))
for line in result.split("\n"): 
    print(line)
```

Result:

```
<a href="mailto:lad at maestro dot com">
<em>ada@graphics.maestro.com</em>
<em>mel@graphics.maestro.com</em>
```

---

Edit:
If your pages can contain non-ASCII characters, you'll need to take care to decode on input and encode on output.
The sample file you uploaded has charset set to `cp-1252`, so let's try decoding from that to Unicode:

```
import codecs 
with codecs.open(filename, encoding="cp1252") as fin:
    decoded = fin.read()
result = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(urllib2.unquote(decoded))
with codecs.open('/output/file.html', 'w', encoding='cp1252') as fou:
    fou.write(result)
```

---

Edit2:
If you don't care about the non-ASCII characters you can simplify a bit:

```
with open(filename) as fin:
    decoded = fin.read().decode('ascii','ignore')
...
```

Comment: While this solution looks good is does throw a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128) error at some places.

Comment: Try using .encode('ascii') on the markup string before feeding it in.

Comment: @mcenley: if you post more detail about how you're getting your data we can provide encoding assistance.

Comment: @bernie I have a list of html pages downloaded. How should I send them to you?

Comment: No no, I believe you. What we'd need is the encoding used for those pages, and how you're reading them. The principle is decode (to Unicode) on input, and encode on output.

Comment: @bernie I can upload my Python program on a gist. Can we take this discussion further on chat?

Comment: @mcenley: perfect, thanks. I'll update my answer. Give me just a moment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9266/discussion-between-mcenley-and-bernie)

Comment: @NiallByrne The same issue persists - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 149: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Not much help to you mcenley- +1 to bernie for taking a look at the encoding of the example file.  It's worth the pounding my rep took here to learn a bit about encoding :) +1 on what turned out to be a pretty interesting question.

Comment: @bernie Thanks Bernie! I must sure look into encoding a bit more. IT's really confusing.

Comment: @NiallByrne No issues mate. I hope to keep some more such interesting questions posted.

Comment: mcenly: you're most welcome. @NiallByrne: you probably know this: I think you can vote to delete your answer and get the rep back if you're so inclined. Happy coding.

Comment: @mcenley: there are various ways to try to do that; however, due to subtle differences between encodings guessing is not typically recommended.

Comment: @bernie Thanks! Apologies to cross post but I'm facing an issue with this method of decoding for quotes. I have posted a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860400/accomodate-two-types-of-quotes-in-a-regex